# Modificar datos en excel con openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

que tal, ando precticando la libreria openpyxl y python, soy relativamente nuevo ando aprendiendo a la par el lenguaje, con esta libreria puedo leer los datos de un excel y quisiera hacer algunos calculos o comparaciones y almacenarlos en el excel, pero al tratar de hacerlo me indica que no se ha podido modificar. alguien me podría indicar de que otra forma se puede hacer?

gracias

```
import openpyxl

book = openpyxl.load_workbook('PLANILLA.xlsx',data_only=True)

#Crear un libro en blanco 
#book = openpyxl.Workbook()

hoja = book.active

#hoja['F4'] = 'Hola'

celdas = hoja ['A2':'F4']
#print(celdas) 
lista_empleados = []

for fila in celdas:
    #print([celda.value for celda in fila]) #Comprensión de listas
    empleado = [celda.value for celda in fila]
    lista_empleados.append(empleado)
##print(lista_empleados)

valor1 = 0
valor2 = 0

for empleado in lista_empleados:
    print(f'El empleado {empleado[0]} es un {empleado[1]} y gana {empleado[2]}')
    res = empleado[2] - empleado[3]
    lista_empleados.append[res]
    print([lista_empleados])
    hoja.append(['DEVENGADO'])
    print(f'El empleado gana {empleado[2]} y se le descuenta {empleado[3]} ,total a consignar {res}')
book.save('PLANILLA.xlsx')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Tienes el excel abierto mientras ejecutas el código?

Comment: Hola , no lo cerre antes de ejecutar, pero no me funcionó me dio error

Answer (score 0):

trata de usar

```
wbw = load_workbook(workBookPath)
ouputListName = wbw.sheetnames

ouput = wbw[ouputListName[0]]
(
        cedulas,
        nombres,
        departamento,
        municipio,
        puesto,
        mesa,
        lider,
        porRevisar,
    ) = ouput [f"A{i}:H{i}"][0]
   ouput[f"A{i}"] = "lo que quieras"
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].